# What would the Big Theta of this be?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So I have this function $$2^n(n+2)^2\log_2n$$
And I simplified it down to this$$2^nn^2\log_2n + 2^{2+n}n\log_2n + 2^{2+n}\log_2n$$
However, I'm not sure what the Big Theta of this function would be. I'm thinking it's $\Theta(2^nn^2\log_2n)$, but I'm not sure if this is correct or if I should simplify it. Could anyone help.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a unique answer (e.g., $\Theta(n)$ and $\Theta(n+2)$ are the same), but your answer is valid since
$$\frac{2^n (n+2)^2 \log_2 n}{2^n n^2 \log_2 n} = \left(1+\frac{2}{n} \right)^2 \to 1.$$
I don't think there is another simpler form you could use.

Comment: +1, :) beat me by 10 seconds

Comment: I don't think $\Theta(n+2)$ is a valid order, not even $\Theta(2n)$. It's just $\Theta(n)$

Comment: @Alex I understand what you're saying (and I know people never use $\Theta(n+2)$ or $\Theta(2n)$), but is there an established definition of "valid order"?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply take the limit, the first terms is $1$, the second and third are
$$
1 + \frac{4}{n} + \frac{4}{n^2} \geq1
$$
and they obviously converge to $1$ from above. At the same time, you can take an upper bound on the function you have:
$$
h(n) \leq 3 f(n)
$$
where $h(n)$ are all three terms, and $f(n)$ is the largest term. As a result,
$$
\frac{h(n)}{f(n)} \leq \frac{3f(n)}{f(n)} = 3
$$
which is also a constant. Hence,
$$
h(n) = \Theta(f(n))
$$